How to integrate Google Login with JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core?
I am working on a project where users can register and log in with their email, password, name, and other details. Upon login, the system generates a JWT token for authentication.
I want to extend this functionality to allow users to log in with Google. Upon a successful Google login, the system should update user details (like email and name) in the database and generate a JWT token. However, I am encountering issues during implementation and suspect I might be missing something in my setup.
Here's my current code - authentication configuration:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;       
})
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientID"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Key"])),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

API controller actions:
[HttpGet("google-login")]
public IActionResult GoogleLogin()
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleCallback")
    };
    return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[HttpGet("google-callback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleCallback()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
    if (!result.Succeeded)
        return Unauthorized();

    // Token Generation Logic
    return Ok(token);
}

Problem: when logging in with Google, after successful authentication, the browser is redirected to the URL:
https://localhost/signin-google?state=...

At this point, the application doesn't handle the request as expected, and I face issues during redirection:

Any help to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
